# Linux module verification failed

Tags: linux, driver, device

so i'm getting this error : "module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel" when i'm trying to put my simple device driver to kernel. I tried recompiling kernel, change my makefile , but nothing helped. At this moment my makefile :

```
obj-m := DeviceD.o

KERNEL_DIR = /usr/src/linux-headers-$(shell uname -r)

all:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNEL_DIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules

clean:
     rm -rf *.o *.ko *.mod.* *.symvers *.order *~
```

also tried this makefile :

```
obj-m += DeviceD.o
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [kvm: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24975377/kvm-module-verification-failed-signature-and-or-required-key-missing-taintin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means you have not used **GPL** in the module description macros.  This is a warning to indicate you are using some non open software kernel module.

To cease to obtain that message, you have to change the parameter of **MODULE_LICENSE()** macro in your drive code to include the GPL string.

Comment: Well it kinda worked :D , i get the same warning but know the drive is working.