# makefile in linux, unable to insert the module

Tags: c, module, makefile, linux-kernel

I'm new in linux programming and I'm struggling with creation on makefile. I got 3 files:
hello.c

```
#include <linux/module.h> /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h> /* Needed for KERN_INFO */
#include "funcs.h"

int init_module(void) {
    asgard();
    return 0;
 }

void cleanup_module(void) {
     printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye world 1.\n");
}
```

funcs.c

```
#include <linux/module.h> /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h> /* Needed for KERN_INFO */
#include "funcs.h"

void asgard(void) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "Asgard balordo\n");
    return;
}
```

funcs.h

```
#include <linux/module.h> /* Needed by all modules */

void asgard(void);
```

Then the makefile:

```
obj-m += hello.o
hello-objs := funcs.o

first:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

all: funcs.o hello.o
    gcc -o start funcs.o hello.o

funcs.o: funcs.c funcs.h
    gcc -C funcs.c

hello.o: hello.c funcs.h
    gcc -C hello.c

clean:
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f ./start
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

When I compile, everything is fine, when i call insmod ./hello.ko it's said that was impossible to insert the module. 
May you tell me where I'm wrong please?

Comment: There are 2 source files, hello.c, and funcs.c, hello.o is ambiguity here. So please try to rename hello.c to hello_1.c, and set hello-objs := funcs.o hello_1.o, and rebuild

Comment: Ok it works now, thanks 4 help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you don't need to call GCC in your makefile to build a module, try this makefile:

```
obj-m += hello.o
hello-objs := funcs.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
```

Also, you could tell the module which function is the entry point and the exit point, and its good to declare module description, author and licensing. ([Why here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x279.html))

Try this:

```
static int __init enter_module(void)
{
    return 0;
}

static void __exit exit_module(void)
{
}

module_init(enter_module);
module_exit(exit_module);

MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("John <john@jonnyland.com>");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("This is the module description.");
```

Kernel keywords `__init` and `__exit` are used to let the Kernel to do optimizations by  removing functions from memory whenever possible.

While macros `module_init` and `module_exit` will register module entry and exit functions.

Comment: Changed, still same result :(

Comment: @alteration What is the kernel version you are building against?

Comment: @alteration Edited the answer to cover Makefile changes.

Comment: Wait, apparently now it runs but doesn't print the message (can't find it in dmesg)

Comment: hello: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel

Comment: @alteration https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24975377/kvm-module-verification-failed-signature-and-or-required-key-missing-taintin
What is your platform ?